# Mineflayer - options.username = options.username ?? 'Player' error

Tags: node.js, minecraft

I was trying to learn how to program a Minecraft Bot and I found Mineflayer. Everything is working fine but when ever I run the program I always get:

```
/home/runner/Minecraft-Bot/node_modules/mineflayer/index.js:63
  options.username = options.username ?? 'Player'
                                       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
```

[The error message I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWAQh.png)

I used the Mineflayer GitHub page and followed word for word but my code still won't run. Any ideas why is it happening? Thanks!
[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7yeQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the line of code in the stack trace: Node.js is unable to interpret the `??` syntax construct. The "??" is called the *nullish coalescing operator* and is a new addition to ECMAScript, so it's only supported in the most recent of runtimes. Make sure you're running Node.js 14.x or later.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you I will start running Node.js 14x and over. Much appreciated!